# list out of range while resigning all the images within a folder

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to resize and normalise all the images in a folder but at the end, it throws an error saying list is out of range

```py
def resize():

    data = []
    
    img_size = 244
    data_dir = r'C:\technocolab project2\archive'
    for img in os.listdir(data_dir):
        try:
            imgPath = os.path.join(data_dir,img)
            images = cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            image_resized = cv2.resize(images,(img_size,img_size))
            data.append(img_resized)
        except:
            pass
        return data
    
data = resize()
print(len(data))

sample = data[0]
print(sample.shape)
```

the error that it shows is given in the figure that says:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are returning your data list in the first iteration of your for loop. You should untab your return return data statemente at the same level of the for loop.

Edit:
This code works perfectly for me

```
import cv2
import os
def resize():
    
    data = []
    
    img_size = 244
    data_dir = "./imgs"
    for img in os.listdir(data_dir):
        try:
            imgPath = os.path.join(data_dir,img)
            images = cv2.imread(imgPath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            image_resized = cv2.resize(images,(img_size,img_size))
            data.append(image_resized)
        except:
            pass
    return data
    
data = resize()
print(len(data))

sample = data[0]
print(sample.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what is happening is: the `img_resized` variable is not declared and the exception is triggered, so you have `pass`, then you return the empty array, since `return` is inside the loop.

Fix the variable name and put `return` outside the loop.